# React/Axios api call returns promises

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, axios, es6-promise

I'm struggling to understand something with my API call through Axios. 
E.G list of tracks is an array with a few tracks as strings. I'm using these tracks to pass into the api call to go through each song and return the lyrics for each. I eventually want to get the length of each, sort them and find the average words in all i.e Coldplay songs. So I want lengthOfSongs to eventually looks like this in the state: lengthOfSongs: [10, 20, 30]

```
    listofTracks.map(track => {
      return api
        .getLyrics(inputArtist, track)
        .then(response => {
          this.setState({ lengthOfSongs: response.split(" ").length });
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log("ERROR");
        });
    });
```

I'm aware a promise has been returned and I've used .then but for some reason when it's consoled it's just giving me back the last one. It'll replace each resolved one rather than add them to the array. So when I render the state on the page it'll show 10 then switch that for 20 when that's resolved and then switch that to 30 when that's resolved etc. But I just want a simple map of all the lengths. I feel like the issue lies with the map or maybe code relating to the promise isn't executed correctly. noob here :( pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue here lies in your usage of setState. Everytime you execute the setState, you're passing exactly one data to the state. Hence at the end of the loop, state contains the last data.

You could try using spread operator on the state.

```
this.setState({
 lengthOfSongs : [...this.state.lengthOfSongs, response.split(" ").length]
});
```

Comment: I tried to spread but wasn't using the state with the length. Thanks so much, that worked!

Comment: Could you select this as the answer?